# Cucumber Record ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, pickle, capybara

Given the following in Cucumber:

```
Given a car exists with title: "Toyota"
And I go to path "/cars"
And I follow "Toyota Page"
And I should be on path "/cars/CAR_ID"
Where CAR_ID is the ID of the car titled "Toyota".
```

How do I figure out that ID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could write it like:

```
Given a car exists with title: "Toyota"
When I go to path "/cars"
And I follow "Toyota Page"
Then I should be on the page for the car: "Toyota"
```

The definition for the last step could be:

```
Then /^I should be on the page for the car: "([^\"]*)"$/ do |car_title|
  car = Car.find_by_title(car_title)
  assert_equal "/cars/#{car.id}", URI.parse(current_url).path
end
```

Comment: Agreed that this is the better approach -- steps can rely on the things that came before, but not on what comes after.  You could make it even simpler by setting an instance variable on the _Given_ step.  (E.g., `@car = [[something]]` and then refer to `@car` later on in your _Then_ statements so you don't have to go finding it again.)

Answer (score 2):

Check out: http://railscasts.com/episodes/186-pickle-with-cucumber

In particular look at the pickle example where he creates a product:

```
Scenario: Show product
  Given a product exists with name: "Milk", price: "2.99"
  When I go to the show page for that product
  Then I should see "Milk" within "h1"
  And I should see "$2.99"
```

Note how he refers to the created product as **that product**.  Pickle will take care of that for you.

Good luck.

Comment: In that case I would write a custom step to find a given car by name, then use shoulda to determine if it is a match.